# How to manually add custom information to the on-hover documentation that vscode provides when hovering on something

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I would like to complete or add custom information to the documentation that VSCode provides when sometimes it doesn't offer as much info as I want.

For example in CSS I've got

```css
box-shadow: 2px 4px 10px 4px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
```

and when I hover over box-shadow it shows me this

[image: Default vscode documentation]

I'ld like to be able to add to the syntax for example to add things like what each parameter of box-shadow does so when I forget I just quickly hover it and remember and same for other stuff that are missing some documentation.

Comment: write an extension with a HoverProvider that shows the info you want

Comment: @rioV8 oh that sounds actually smart, if there's no official solution i might just try that!

Comment: first search the Marketplace if it is not done already by somebody